Identifying client user in javafx application with jpro-one
Is there a way to identify the current user of my application anywhere inside my javafx application code that is running for the web using jpro? I would like, anywhere inside my java app, to be able to retrieve a way to identify the current user. I am making a game engine in kotlin using javafx and when i tried to port it to the web using jpro, i got errors because i was using singletons, so i need some way to identify the client to get the instance of that client, otherwise all client would have the same instances, which is not what i want.
I tried using the session package from https://github.com/JPro-one/JPro-Platform but i wasn't able to use it for a way to identify the client, the lack of documentation also make it kinda hard to use.

The class java.lang.System has Properties; among them  user.name may be available.

In the context of a normal java application, you are right, however using jpro, it would return the username of the user of the server, which won't help me with my problem, thank you for trying to resolve my problem thought!

I'm unfamiliar with JPro, but that makes sense. At a guess, would the com.jpro.webapi.WebAPI notion of a session instance ID be suitable?

I’m not familiar with JPro but presumably there must be some way to pass command line arguments to the Java code. Just pass the user id as a command line argument.

Having had a very speedy look at the examples, the "session package" looks like something to be used by the 'client'. I quote that deliberately, since you seem to be thinking that this is a client/server technology of sorts. I suspect that it isn't, much in a way that applets weren't. Yes there's a web response involved, but I think maybe only to the extent of "return this tech so a gui can be made in the browser"

Given this arctitecture, does running this example offer any insight.

@trashgod that's slightly more 'client/server-ish' than I thought, but not significantly so to change my overall impression contained in my last comment

@g00se: Thank you for commenting. I see that a JPro Session "remembers the user, based on a cookie." Having used this approach in servlets, I'm hopeful that it might be useful to the OP. I'd welcome your insight.
